# Invalid or courrpt jar file

Tags: java

Hello so i am making a game in java and it runs with no errors in my ide perfectly fine but when i build it and run it not in my ide it says Invalid or courrpt jar file. I will send the code in pastebin as it is really long but, if you know how to fix it the please tell me be cause i have been trouble shooting if for ages trying different ides building it but still no work.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TicTacToe implements Runnable {

    private String ip = "localhost";
    private int port = 22222;
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private JFrame frame;
    private final int WIDTH = 506;
    private final int HEIGHT = 527;
    private Thread thread;

    private Painter painter;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private DataInputStream dis;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private BufferedImage board;
    private BufferedImage redX;
    private BufferedImage blueX;
    private BufferedImage redCircle;
    private BufferedImage blueCircle;

    private String[] spaces = new String[9];

    private boolean yourTurn = false;
    private boolean circle = true;
    private boolean accepted = false;
    private boolean unableToCommunicateWithOpponent = false;
    private boolean won = false;
    private boolean enemyWon = false;
    private boolean tie = false;

    private int lengthOfSpace = 160;
    private int errors = 0;
    private int firstSpot = -1;
    private int secondSpot = -1;

    private Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 32);
    private Font smallerFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);
    private Font largerFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 50);

    private String waitingString = "Waiting for another player";
    private String unableToCommunicateWithOpponentString = "Unable to communicate with opponent.";
    private String wonString = "You won!";
    private String enemyWonString = "Opponent won!";
    private String tieString = "Game ended in a tie.";

    private int[][] wins = new int[][] { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }, { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 }, { 0, 4, 8 }, { 2, 4, 6 } };

    /**
     * <pre>
     * 0, 1, 2
     * 3, 4, 5
     * 6, 7, 8
     * </pre>
     */

    public TicTacToe() {
        System.out.println("Please input the IP: ");
        ip = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please input the port: ");
        port = scanner.nextInt();
        while (port < 1 || port > 65535) {
            System.out.println("The port you entered was invalid, please input another port: ");
            port = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        loadImages();

        painter = new Painter();
        painter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        if (!connect()) initializeServer();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        frame.setContentPane(painter);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        thread = new Thread(this, "TicTacToe");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            tick();
            painter.repaint();

            if (!circle && !accepted) {
                listenForServerRequest();
            }

        }
    }

    private void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, null);
        if (unableToCommunicateWithOpponent) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(smallerFont);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(unableToCommunicateWithOpponentString);
            g.drawString(unableToCommunicateWithOpponentString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
            return;
        }

        if (accepted) {
            for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
                if (spaces[i] != null) {
                    if (spaces[i].equals("X")) {
                        if (circle) {
                            g.drawImage(redX, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                        } else {
                            g.drawImage(blueX, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                        }
                    } else if (spaces[i].equals("O")) {
                        if (circle) {
                            g.drawImage(blueCircle, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                        } else {
                            g.drawImage(redCircle, (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3), (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3), null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (won || enemyWon) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawLine(firstSpot % 3 * lengthOfSpace + 10 * firstSpot % 3 + lengthOfSpace / 2, (int) (firstSpot / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (firstSpot / 3) + lengthOfSpace / 2, secondSpot % 3 * lengthOfSpace + 10 * secondSpot % 3 + lengthOfSpace / 2, (int) (secondSpot / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (secondSpot / 3) + lengthOfSpace / 2);

                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.setFont(largerFont);
                if (won) {
                    int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(wonString);
                    g.drawString(wonString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
                } else if (enemyWon) {
                    int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(enemyWonString);
                    g.drawString(enemyWonString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
                }
            }
            if (tie) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.setFont(largerFont);
                int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(tieString);
                g.drawString(tieString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
            }
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(font);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(waitingString);
            g.drawString(waitingString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
        }

    }

    private void tick() {
        if (errors >= 10) unableToCommunicateWithOpponent = true;

        if (!yourTurn && !unableToCommunicateWithOpponent) {
            try {
                int space = dis.readInt();
                if (circle) spaces[space] = "X";
                else spaces[space] = "O";
                checkForEnemyWin();
                checkForTie();
                yourTurn = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                errors++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkForWin() {
        for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
            if (circle) {
                if (spaces[wins[i][0]] == "O" && spaces[wins[i][1]] == "O" && spaces[wins[i][2]] == "O") {
                    firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                    secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                    won = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (spaces[wins[i][0]] == "X" && spaces[wins[i][1]] == "X" && spaces[wins[i][2]] == "X") {
                    firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                    secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                    won = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkForEnemyWin() {
        for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
            if (circle) {
                if (spaces[wins[i][0]] == "X" && spaces[wins[i][1]] == "X" && spaces[wins[i][2]] == "X") {
                    firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                    secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                    enemyWon = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (spaces[wins[i][0]] == "O" && spaces[wins[i][1]] == "O" && spaces[wins[i][2]] == "O") {
                    firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                    secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                    enemyWon = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkForTie() {
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
            if (spaces[i] == null) {
                return;
            }
        }
        tie = true;
    }

    private void listenForServerRequest() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            accepted = true;
            System.out.println("CLIENT HAS REQUESTED TO JOIN, AND WE HAVE ACCEPTED");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean connect() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            accepted = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to connect to the address: " + ip + ":" + port + " | Starting a server");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to the server.");
        return true;
    }

    private void initializeServer() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 8, InetAddress.getByName(ip));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        yourTurn = true;
        circle = false;
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        try {
            board = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/board.png"));
            redX = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/redX.png"));
            redCircle = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/redCircle.png"));
            blueX = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/blueX.png"));
            blueCircle = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/blueCircle.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();
    }

    private class Painter extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Painter() {
            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocus();
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            addMouseListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            render(g);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (accepted) {
                if (yourTurn && !unableToCommunicateWithOpponent && !won && !enemyWon) {
                    int x = e.getX() / lengthOfSpace;
                    int y = e.getY() / lengthOfSpace;
                    y *= 3;
                    int position = x + y;

                    if (spaces[position] == null) {
                        if (!circle) spaces[position] = "X";
                        else spaces[position] = "O";
                        yourTurn = false;
                        repaint();
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

                        try {
                            dos.writeInt(position);
                            dos.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            errors++;
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        System.out.println("DATA WAS SENT");
                        checkForWin();
                        checkForTie();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you say the code is fine and it works in your IDE and the error is related to the jar file then there really is no point in showing all that code. Instead: how do you build the jar file, how are you running it?

Comment: Why do you think your code is wrong and not how you create the jar file?

Comment: I have made a artifact as i am using intellj and it builds with no errors just does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because of missing or wrong MANIFEST.MF file. The contents of this file should be like:

```
Main-Class: com.your.package.Main
```

You can refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) link for more details